# Solving simple Probability with variational inference

Tags: probability, bayesian

I have P(X) (someone standing infront of a house) and I have P(Z|X) (dog is barking given someone is standing infront of a house).

If I would like to find out probability of P(Z) (Dog is barking) or P(X|Z) (Someone is standing infront of a house given dog is barking) I could use a law of total probability or Bayes network. This is really simple model with P(Z), which is tractable.

Now, let's assume P(Z) is not tractablee and I would need to use variational inference to solve this problem.

Could anyone please let me describe how we would do that in pseudo, non algebra way? I know a concept of Kl Divergence and lowerbound, but I just can not visualize the whole concept. Could you let me know what would be steps? I would appreciate it.

Comment: In paragraphs 2 and 3, what  does "traceable" mean?

Comment: @kimchilover Sorry, what I meant is that integral of P(Z) would be not possible to solve. In the case I gave, it's pretty easy, but let's just assume for the better understading of VI, that this integral is not possible to solve and we would need to use VI to do so. I would better understand VI, if I could picture a scenario I wrote about.

Comment: So "traceable" is "tractable" ?

Comment: yes. thank you. i'll fix